# Handling Authentication Failure with Springboot & Spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

In a Rest appplication developped with Spring, I use POJO classes, DTO and entity for users management. Here is an abstract of my entity class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@Getter @Setter
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String userKeyId;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 120, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String encryptedPassword;

    @Column
    private String emailVerificationToken;

    @Column(name = "email_verification_status", columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE")
    private Boolean emailVerificationStatus = false;

    @Column(name="is_account_non_expired")
    private Boolean isAccountNonExpired;

    @Column(name="is_account_non_locked")
    private Boolean isAccountNonLocked;

    @Column(name="is_credentials_non_expired")
    private Boolean isCredentialsNonExpired;

    @Column(name="is_enabled")
    private Boolean isEnabled;

    @Column(name="is_logged_in")
    private Boolean isLoggedIn;
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade= { CascadeType.PERSIST }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<RoleEntity> roles;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="created_at")
    private Date createdAt;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="updated_at")
    private Date updatedAt;
}
```

I have a UserServiceImpl class that implements UserDetails

I do have then to implement loadUserByUsername

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    if( userEntity == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User email is not in the database");
    } else {
        validateLoginAttempt(userEntity);
        log.info("Returning User : " + userEntity.getFirstName() + " " + userEntity.getLastName());
        userEntity.setLastLoginDateDisplay(userEntity.getLastLoginDate());
        userEntity.setLastLoginDate(new Date());
        userRepository.save(userEntity);
        return new UserPrincipal(userEntity);
    }
}
```

If user exists I call a method to validate authentication.

```
private void validateLoginAttempt(UserEntity user) {
    if(user.getIsAccountNonLocked()) {
        if(loginAttemptService.hasExceededMaxAttempts(user.getEmail())) {
            user.setIsAccountNonLocked(Boolean.FALSE);
        } else {
            user.setIsAccountNonLocked(Boolean.TRUE);
        }
    } else {
        loginAttemptService.evictUserFromLoginAttemptCache(user.getEmail());
    }
}
```

This method allows me to check if the user account is locked or not and if user tried to connect too many times.

My LoginAttemptServiceImpl is the following:

```
@Service
public class LoginAttemptServiceImpl implements LoginAttemptService {
    public static final int MAXIMUM_AUTH_ATTEMPT = 5;
    public static final int AUTH_ATTEMPT_INCREMENT = 1;
    private LoadingCache<String, Integer> loginAttemptCache;
    private String username;

    public LoginAttemptServiceImpl() {
        super();
        loginAttemptCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .maximumSize(10000)
                .build(new CacheLoader<>() {
                    @Override
                    public Integer load(String key) {
                        return 0;
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void evictUserFromLoginAttemptCache(String username) {
        loginAttemptCache.invalidate(username);
    }

    @Override
    public void addUserToLoginAttemptCache(String username) {
        int attempts = 0;
        try {
            attempts = AUTH_ATTEMPT_INCREMENT + loginAttemptCache.get(username);
            loginAttemptCache.put(username, attempts);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasExceededMaxAttempts(String username) {
        try {
            return loginAttemptCache.get(username) >= MAXIMUM_AUTH_ATTEMPT;
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLoginAttempts(String username) throws ExecutionException {
        return loginAttemptCache.get(username);
    }
}
```

I also implemented an event listener for authentication failure:

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFailureListener {
    private final LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService;

    @Autowired
    public AuthenticationFailureListener(LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService) {
        this.loginAttemptService = loginAttemptService;
    }

    @EventListener
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent event) {
        Object principal = event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        if (principal instanceof String) {
            String username = (String) event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            loginAttemptService.addUserToLoginAttemptCache(username);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally my AuthenticationFilter allows me to manage successful and unsuccessful response:

```
@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response,
                                        FilterChain chain,
                                        Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String userName = ((UserPrincipal)authResult.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
    // built the token
    String token = Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(userName)
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SecurityConstants.getTokenSecret())
            .compact();

    UserService userService = (UserService) SpringApplicationContext.getBean("userServiceImpl");
    UserDto userDto = userService.getUser(userName);

    response.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING_USERID, userDto.getUserKeyId());
    response.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING, SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
}

@SneakyThrows
@Override
protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                                          HttpServletResponse response,
                                          AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // super.unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);
    int attempts;

    if(loginAttemptService.hasExceededMaxAttempts(this.username)) {
        attempts = loginAttemptService.getLoginAttempts(this.username);
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Attempt number " + attempts + ": Account is locked for 15 minutes");
    } else {
        attempts = loginAttemptService.getLoginAttempts(this.username);
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Attempt number " + attempts + ": " + (SecurityConstants.MAX_AUTH_ATTEMPTS - attempts) + " - before account is blocked");
    }
}
```

Authentication works when it's successful... My issue concerns failure and i have 3 issues:

1. I would like to return an object in case of failure. the response.sendError should do the job but it doesn't. I also tried to return a Json response : https://www.baeldung.com/servlet-json-response
2. I use Guava cache but I also update database at the same time by setting isAccountNonLocked to false. I'd like to set the value to True once the cache is cleared.
3. I do not update the count of attempt in unsuccessfulAuthentication method. My response is always : Attempt number 0: 5 - before account is blocked

Thanks for help and for reading the whole text!

Comment: What is your error ?

Comment: I do not have error messages. I just do not have any response in a response body... I do not retrieve the count of attempts and i don't know how to update database when i clean the cache.

Comment: I hope you are aware that building your own custom security solution is bad practice.

Comment: I use Spring Security to implement it. How then do you handle unsucessful authentication without overriding Spring Security methods ? If i have to have specific behavior for avoiding brute force attack ? If i want user to renew password after 3 false authentication, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For issue 3:
In my WebSecurity class which extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, I implemented a bean in order to inject it in my AuthenticationFilter.

Here is my bean:

```
@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

Here is my AuthenticationFilter class. I initially added this class as component (bad idea which generated error messages).

```
// @Component
public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService;
    private String username;

    public AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.loginAttemptService = loginAttemptService;
    }
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding issue number 1, you can use a similar approach as the one mentioned in the link you posted, but use response.getWriter().write(String) and Jackson's ObjectMapper, like this:

```
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        
        response.getWriter().write(mapper.writeValueAsString( /*Your custom POJO here */ ));
```

Comment: i also tried this without success unfortunatelly...

Comment: Is unsuccessfulAuthentication triggered when failed authentication? If so, do you get an error when using the code above?

Answer (score 0):

For issue 2: I found a trick that solves it. Instead of updating the database at the same time i clear the cache, I make the update at login validation...

```
private void validateLoginAttempt(UserEntity user) {
    if(user.getIsAccountNonLocked()) {
        if(loginAttemptService.hasExceededMaxAttempts(user.getEmail())) {
            user.setIsAccountNonLocked(Boolean.FALSE);
        } else {
            user.setIsAccountNonLocked(Boolean.TRUE);
        }
    } else {
        if(!loginAttemptService.hasExceededMaxAttempts(user.getEmail())) {
            user.setIsAccountNonLocked(Boolean.TRUE);
        }
        loginAttemptService.evictUserFromLoginAttemptCache(user.getEmail());
    }
}
```